# Why does my function players_list() keep looping when it's only called once?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm writing the code for a game and during my so-far testing the function players_list() keeps looping even tough it is only called once. The function sixteen_is_dead(players)'s code is only for testing purposes. Can anyone tell me how to resolve the problem?
I want to get the list from players_list() and run sixteen_is_dead(players) with it.

```
import random


def sixteen_is_dead(players):
    if players[0][1] is True:
        print("Player 1 is not a Human!")


def players_list():
    players = []
    player_count2 = 0
    player_count = int(input("How many players are there?: "))
    for x in range(0, player_count):
        player_count2 += 1
        player_name = input("What's the {}. players name?: ".format(player_count2))
        player_is_bot = input("Is the {}. ? player a bot? J/N: ".format(player_count2))
        if player_is_bot == "J":
            is_bot = False
        elif player_is_bot == "N":
            is_bot = True
        players.append((player_name, is_bot))
    return players
    
        

players_list()
players = players_list()
print(players)
```

Comment: You've shown two calls to `players_list()`. What's the problem?

Comment: I may be blind but where is the second call? One is below the functions but the other?

Comment: `players = players_list()` is immediately after the first call

Comment: Hmm, the problem went away after I took that part of the code out but I thought I need it to get players from the function and use it in sixteen_is_dead(players). Am I doing it wrong and the solution to doing that is a different one?

Comment: On its own `players_list()` calls the function, but returns the output into nothing. The later is correct, but you may also use `sixteen_is_dead(players_list())`

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function 2 times, you just have to put:

```
players= players_list()
print(players)
```